# MYSQL case when with concatenation

Tags: mysql, sql, concatenation, case-when

I cant seem to get the syntax correct when I'm trying to add conditions that must be satisfied before concatenating multiple inputs I will leave code below but essentially CASE when 'Condition'THEN concatenate these strings + columns THEN give me X ELSE 0 essentially like any other case when statement but with concat. I have played around with the IF statement but that hasn't been successful either ( I primarily use MYSQL )

the reason I am using concat twice is the info is in two separate tables so I need to use the || to produce the output I need but I want 10 case when conditions where it will shot out that concatenation based on if one of those conditions is true

```
CASE WHEN 'specific condition' THEN concat('string',employee2.firstname) || concat('/employerid/',employee.lastname) ELSE 'Null')
WHEN ....
WHEN.....
WHEN ....END) as employee_ID
```

Comment: What do you to achieve by || ? also an else only stands at the end of the case right before the END

Comment: Might be worth noting that in MySQL, `CONCAT()` will return `NULL` if ANY of the expressions are `NULL`.

Answer (score 3):

The operator `||` is the [logical OR operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/logical-operators.html#operator_or) in MySql and not a concatenation operator (unless PIPES_AS_CONCAT SQL mode is enabled).

> the reason I am using concat twice is the info is in two separate
>   tables

If what you want is to concatenate all 4 values then all you need is access to both tables from the `CASE` expression and then there is no reason to use `concat()` twice .

`Concat()` can take multiple parameters, so instead of:

```
concat('string',employee2.firstname) || concat('/employerid/',employee.lastname)
```

do this:

```
concat('string',employee2.firstname, '/employerid/',employee.lastname)
```

Note: `'Null'` is not `NULL`, it's a string literal.
So do something like this:

```
CASE 
  WHEN 'specific condition' THEN concat('string',employee2.firstname,'/employerid/',employee.lastname) 
  WHEN ....
  WHEN.....
  WHEN ....
END as employee_ID
```

The `ELSE` part is not needed if you want it just to return `NULL`.

Comment: For some reason when I tried to add all 4 under one concat it was giving me an error but when I combined them with || it gave me the correct output.  Thank for the Case when syntax I will continue to play around with this much appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure you are using Mysql?

Comment: It's been a while... but as I rea from your previous comment: *when I tried to add all 4 under one concat it was giving me an error* this can't be MySql. Check this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat Mysql supports multiple operands with concat().

Comment: My apologies that was written on Vertica